# "Encounter nonnumerical numbers at t==0" when using NDsolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

The codes goes like this:

```
Manipulate[{aF, adF, bF, bdF} = 
  NDSolveValue[{a'[t] == -I*a[t] (deltaa + 2*g*Re[b[t]]) - I*omegaa - 
      a[t]*kapa/2, 
    b'[t] == -I (b[t]*deltab + g*Abs[a[t]]^2 + omegab) - b[t]*gamma/2,
     a[0] == 1, b[0] == 1}, {a, a', b, b'}, {t, 0, 500}];
 ParametricPlot[{Re[bdF[t]], Re[bF[t]]}, {t, 0, 200}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {aF, None}, {adF, None}, {bF, 
  None}, {bdF, None}, {g, 0.02, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {kapa, 
  20000, 50000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {gamma, 20000, 120000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {deltaa, -18000000, 18000000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {deltab, -18000000, 18000000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {g, deltaa, deltab, omegaa, omegab, gamma, kapa}]
```

How should I solve such a problem? I have encounter it many times and sometimes it suddenly go away, sometimes doesn't, like in this case.

Comment: I think you’d be better off using `ParametricNDSolveValue` outside `Manipulate` to generate a parametric solution, the plug in the values of the parameters within Manipulate, and plot.

Comment: Diagnostic toolkit: #1 Reason: Undefined parameters (all must have numeric values). #2 Reason: Divide by zero at the initial condition when you solve for the highest-order derivatives. #3 Reason: Latent definitions (some symbol was given a value, but the code assumes it does not; and you forgot you did that). Methods for solving: A. Proofread; if your eyes are weak like mine, use Find menu command to search for each parameter, isolating code in its own notebook if needed. B. Solve the DEs for the highest order derivatives and plug in the initial conditions; `Solve` and `ReplaceAll` can be used

Comment: ...C. `Quit[]` the kernel; delete the `Manipulate` output and `Quit[]` the kernel.